# Jetty Tapestry Hot Deployment = server restart?

Tags: java, jetty, tapestry

could someone confirm that the tapestry hot deployment with Jetty is a: "scan the project for changes and restart the server?"

Or is it: monitor changes and replace new files on server, but do not restart it?

Atm I'm using jetty to monitor every 5 seconds my project, and if changes are detected it restarts the server?

But is this called "hot deployment"? Bc I do no really save time if the server has to be restarted anyway after changes are made?

ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot deployment means that component classes, templates and services (when using Tapestry IOC) are reloaded without a server restart when they are changed. This behavior is switched off and on with the `SymbolConstants.PRODUCTION_MODE` switch.

For details, see the [Class Reloading section](http://tapestry.apache.org/class-reloading.html) in the docs.

Comment: so if I switch production mode to `false` hot deploy should work out of the box, right?

Comment: yes, rtfm. "Troubleshooting Live Class Reloading" in hennings link.